# Agrupar fechas y sumar cantidad

Tags: mysql, sql, sumatoria

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta donde agrupe las fechas a una semana, y sea posible sumar la cantidad.

Por ejemplo del `2019-04-01` al `2019-04-09` me de una suma total de la columna cantidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir basado en la imagen, colocar "Semana 1" y cantidad = 15641

¿Es posible, hacer una consulta así?

De antemano gracias...

Comment: Hola HugoSoft, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, puedes editar tu pregunta las veces que sea necesario, y agregar el contenido pertinente, siempre como texto.

Comment: Hola Hugo, bienvenido! Primero deberías definir como saber cuantos dias tiene una semana ya que lo normal es que sean 7 días. ¿Por qué seria la "Semana 1"? ¿Que pasaría si hubiese fechas anteriores, que semana sería? Lo que se suele utilizar es el número de semana del año.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas cómo funciona la comunidad. De paso ganas estrellas y reputación. Respecto a tu pregunta, tal y como la planteas si se puede... Para ello puedes usar `SUM`, `WHERE` Y `BETWEEN`. Edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado para tratar de darte una mejor guía.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, existe la función `WEEKOFYEAR()` que, a partir de una fecha, calcula la semana del año a la que pertenece. Teniendo esto en cuenta, puedes agrupar por este dato calculado y sumar:

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(fecha) semana,
  SUM(cantidad) cantidad
  FROM tabla
  GROUP BY 1;
```

El resultado que obtendrás será:

```
+--------+----------+
| semana | cantidad |
+--------+----------+
|     14 |    11071 |
|     15 |     6946 |
+--------+----------+
```

Porque las fechas que aportas tienen estas características:

```
+------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
| fecha      | YEARWEEK(fecha) | WEEKOFYEAR(fecha) | WEEKDAY(fecha) | DAYNAME(fecha) |
+------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2019-04-01 |          201913 |                14 |              0 | Monday         |
| 2019-04-02 |          201913 |                14 |              1 | Tuesday        |
| 2019-04-03 |          201913 |                14 |              2 | Wednesday      |
| 2019-04-04 |          201913 |                14 |              3 | Thursday       |
| 2019-04-05 |          201913 |                14 |              4 | Friday         |
| 2019-04-08 |          201914 |                15 |              0 | Monday         |
| 2019-04-09 |          201914 |                15 |              1 | Tuesday        |
| 2019-04-10 |          201914 |                15 |              2 | Wednesday      |
+------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Verás que hay diferentes criterios para numerar las semanas e incluso los días. Pero siempre puedes hacer los ajustes que necesites con  `fecha + INTERVAL 3 DAY`, donde el 3 será el número de días que necesites para ajustar las semanas a las especificaciones que debas cumplir.

Eso que haces de agrupar los días de 7 en 7 y llamarlo "semanas" lo podrías resolver numerando las fechas, dividiendo entre 7 y redondeando:

```
set @i:=0;
SELECT n,SUM(cantidad) cantidad
  FROM (
    SELECT *,CEIL((@i:=@i+1)/7) n
      FROM tabla  
      ORDER BY fecha
  ) c1 GROUP BY 1;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+------+----------+
| n    | cantidad |
+------+----------+
|    1 |    15641 |
|    2 |     2376 |
+------+----------+
```

Pero, por favor, no llames a eso semanas. Una semana es algo más que un grupo de 7 días, deben ser al menos consecutivos y empezar en lunes o domingo, dependiendo de la región.

Con respecto a la formulación de la pregunta, considera los comentarios que te han hecho. En este caso la he respondido, a pesar de no estar completa, porque acabas de llegar a SO (bienvenido), la pregunta es buena y puede ayudar a más personas, pero siempre debes incluir el dataset en modo texto, no imágenes, y el código de lo que hayas intentado.

Facilito el dataset para que se pueda probar el código:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla(
  fecha date,
  cantidad int
  );
INSERT INTO tabla (fecha, cantidad) VALUES
  ('2019-04-01',1670),
  ('2019-04-02',2277),
  ('2019-04-03',2466),
  ('2019-04-04',1960),
  ('2019-04-05',2698),
  ('2019-04-08',2202),
  ('2019-04-09',2368),
  ('2019-04-10',2376);
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, efectivamente soy no nuevo una disculpa pero lo tomare en cuenta, @David JP, me sirve excelente solo que mi base de datos es robusta y me suma la cantidad de semana 14 de 3 años, muchas gracias

Comment: Prueba entonces con la función `YEARWEEK()` en vez de `WEEKOFYEAR()`